# Identify all files having no permission for others using find command

Tags: permissions, find

I want to identify all files which does not have any permission for `others` irrespective of any permission for `user` and `groups` . How the `find` command will look like. e.g

```
drwxrws--- 2 jboss  users 4096 Sep 14  2012 answ
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . ! \( -perm -o=r -o -perm -o=w -o -perm -o=x \)
```

Comment: Why not `! -perm /007`? Is that less compatible?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - no, but i don't even think that works for anything. what is the `/` supposed to do? anyway, `-perm 0007` only matches files for which every permission bit is off except *all* of the `o`ther bits. So it doesn't match `dwrxwrxwrx` or `dwrxrw-rw-` or any of that. Splitting them out and `-o` ring the three bits with the `-` hyphen works to match any file for which any `o`ther permission bit is set.

Comment: `/007` is disjunction. You could just have given it a try...

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I did just give it a try and it was syntax error. What is disjunction?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I guess w/ GNU `find` that does work. It's usually not at the fore of `$PATH` on my system, though, because it's kind of slow. The AST `find` can do most of what it can - and a lot more besides - but also hooks into the `locate` database - and so is usually by far my most preferred `find` to find first in `$PATH`,

Comment: disjunction is OR

Comment: From the GNU `find` documentation: "A *pmode* that starts with ‘/’ matches if *any* of the file mode bits set in *mode* are set for the file; bits not set in *mode* are ignored. This is a GNU extension." `-perm /007` matches if `o+r` is set, *or* (non-exclusive) `o+w` is set, *or* (non-exclusive again) `o+x` is set (it's a disjunction); negating that gives the requested result.

Comment: @StephenKitt - yeah, i did look it up myself afterward and found the same as i noted above. its just not usual for me to encounter a gnu feature not implemented in the ast `find` - generally its the other way round. and so i didn't know. still, i think this is a pretty good example of why such syntax shorthand  is probably not a good idea to generally recommend.

Comment: @mikeserv indeed, it's nice to have once you know it but it's neither easily discoverable nor easily grokkable if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . ! -perm /007                ### In GNU find.
```